# Datorama free version in MC Corporate License

Tags: marketing-cloud, datorama

Is there a free version of Datorama standard report included in the MC corporate license?
I've found this [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_dat_datorama_reports.htm&type=5) but I'm not sure about the information provided...

Answer (score 0):

Following statement in that article indicates that Datorama reports are available in certain editions for free.:

> Datorama Reports—This standard version is included in Pro editions and higher.

So, you will have to check if you are in Professional edition or higher.

Datorama Report Advanced is available at additional cost.

Comment: I know this might not have been obvious from the question, but OP asked about Marketing Cloud, and not Sales Cloud.

Comment: @LukasLunow The [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_dat_datorama_reports.htm&type=5) mentioned by OP is documentation for Mktg Cloud and the statement I've highlighted is from the same article. So, it is for MC & not Sales cloud. Am I missing something here?

Comment: You are telling how to find edition in Sales Cloud, and not MC: *So, you will have to check if you are in Professional edition or higher. You can find your edition from the production org using the steps mentioned here.*

Comment: Got it @LukasLunow. I guess I overlooked that bit. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may already have Datorama reports enabled (if you purchased Salesforce Marketing Cloud on or after September 1st, 2021, and are using Pro, Corporate, or Enterprise editions).  If you do not have, to enable these reports you will have to get in touch with the Account Executive to provision this on your account.

Check  [details](https://www.salesforceben.com/the-drip/datorama-reports-for-marketing-cloud/) and required [permission](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_dat_required_permissions_for_discover_reports.htm&type=5) to access for Datorama Reports.

Thanks